# The role column does not appear in the Postgresql table

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm new to spring boot and jpa and have created this entity called user which has @OneToMany mapping to another table that is role. When I boot the project, every column appears except role. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong here. My role entity looks like this -

Role

```
package com.userservice.usermanagement.models;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;




@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role2 {
    /**
     * Model for role with all the attributes
     */
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      @Column(name = "role_id", nullable = false, length = 1024)
      private int role_id;   
      
      @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 1024)
      private String name;

      public Role2() {

      }

    public int getRole_id() {
        return role_id;
    }

    public void setRole_id(int role_id) {
        this.role_id = role_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

      
    }
```

And User

```
package com.userservice.usermanagement.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;




@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User2 {
    /**
     * User model
     */ 
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 1024)
      private int id;     
      @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 1024)
      private String username;
      @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 1024)
      private String email;   
      @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 1024)
      private String password;
      @Column(name = "customername", nullable = false, length = 1024)
      private String customername;    
      @Column(name = "customerid", nullable = false, length = 1024)
      private String customerid;      
      @Column(name = "description", nullable = false, length = 1024)
      private String description;      
     
      @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
      @JoinTable(name="user_role", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
      private Set<Role2> roles = new HashSet<>();;
      
      public User2() {
      }

      public User2(String username, String email, String customername,String customerid,String description, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.customername = customername;
        this.customerid = customerid;
        this.description = description;
        this.password = password;
      } 
      

    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

      public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
      }
      
      
      public String getUsername() {
        return username;
      }

      public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
      }

      
      public String getEmail() {
        return email;
      }

      public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
      }

     
      public String getPassword() {
        return password;
      }

      public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
      }

     
      
      public String getCustomername() {
        return customername;
    }

    
    public void setCustomername(String customername) {
        this.customername = customername;
    }

    
    public String getCustomerid() {
        return customerid;
    }
    
    
    public void setCustomerid(String customerid) {
        this.customerid = customerid;
    }

    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    
    
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    
    
     public Set<Role2> getRoles() {
        return roles;
      }
    
    public void setRoles(Set<Role2> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    
    


    }
```

In user if I use jointable and post data, everything else shows up but user_role and roles is empty. If I remove jointable to have the column in the User table itself, the role column is missing from user table. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: OneToMany  means that the that for example role it is going to have the reference of user, is that what you want?

Comment: Hi macro, thanks for replying what I want is that one user can have many roles. I'm not sure I quite understand  the reference part in your comment

Comment: Ok, and the role belongs to one user?

Comment: Yes, the role belongs to one user

Comment: if that the case when you remove the JoinTable, you can't see the user_id in the role table?

Comment: No, I removed it and still  I dont see anything :(

Comment: could your try adding @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") in the user class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222504/discussion-between-marco-and-yash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove

> @JoinTable(name="user_role", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"),
> inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"))

because it's for ManyToMany relationship and instead just put:

> @JoinColumn(name="user_id")

With this you going to have a user_id field in Role table, and it's going to work.